# why doesnt it stay highlighted in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('.count_links').hover( function(){
     $(this).addClass("highlight");
   },
   function(){
     $(this).removeClass("highlight");
   });
   $('.count_links').click(function(){
     $('.count_links').not(this).removeClass('highlight');
     $(this).addClass("highlight");
   });
});
```

but the link class never stays after its clicked

I want the hover effect and the click effect

Comment: Why not just use css? Like .count_links:hover {// css from highlight class}

Comment: Looks like you're adding and removing the highlight class as you'd like, except that the mouseout code of your hover() is removing the highlight.  The click() code isn't causing your problem, it's the hover().

Comment: @Adam: Because he's not really doing hover, see the *"but the link class never stays after its [sic] clicked"*

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder -  In that case use another pseudo class like :visited

Answer (score 2):

You're removing the `highlight` class when the cursor leaves the element.

It doesn't matter whether you add the class on click or on hover, the second function passed to `.hover` (which is called on mouse-out) removes the class.

You might consider adding a different class on click, like 'selected'.

Comment: Or not adding the class until the user clicks, and having the same rule for `element:hover` and `element.selected` (assuming IE6 support isn't required, which it may be).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand that you want to do I suggest that piece of code

```
$(function() {
  $('.count_links').hover( function(){
     $(this).addClass("highlight");
   },
   function(){
     $(this).removeClass("highlight");
   });
   $('.count_links').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("highlight");
     $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
   });
});
```

When click you unbind the hover handler

Comment: *"`$(this).hover(function () {}, function(){});`"* Gak. That doesn't unbind anything. it just **adds** empty functions to the event handler list (without removing the earlier ones). To actually unbind, [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 1):

It is staying, but you're removing it again once you hover over and out again. You'll want a way to detect how you added the class. Maybe another dummy class, such as

```
function(){
  $(this).addClass('highlight click')'
}
```

Then you can look for this in the hover and not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a console log to your two hover functions.  You can see in some browsers the "out" function is called multiple times even though the cursor is still over the item.  I'm unsure what causes this strange behavior.

Comment: No, you're thinking of `mouseout`. `hover` uses `mouseleave`, which behaves differently (doesn't bubble).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple workaround would be to create to highlight classes with identical CSS styles, hover_highlight and click_highlight.  Add and remove the associated class with the action. So if you click, you have click_highlight added, which the hover out action won't remove because it's toggling hover_highlight.  Then your actions aren't in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.count_links').click(function(){
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('highlight');
     $(this).addClass('highlight').unbind('hover');
   });
```

and 2 different classes will be better for highlighting and Click.